# owncloud - docker - location of data and mysql data directories on the host?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, owncloud

I'm installing the owncloud server on a macOS machine, so I have to use the docker image. The [docker installation documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/docker/) says the install:

> mounts the data and MySQL data directories on the host for persistent storage

But I cannot find the location.

The docker-composer.yml file mentions

```
services:
  owncloud:
    volumes:
      - files:/mnt/data
```

but this is not a path on my host, so obviously I'm missing something.

Thanks,

Comment: Volumes have a `source` and a `destination` field. You are obviously looking for the first one. Did you try to use any `inspect` command?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, location of your data is "files". 
In following case, location of data is "/var/mysql/data" :

```
services:
    owncloud:
        volumes:
            - /var/mysql/data:/mnt/data
```

Comment: If you look at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) you will notice that your answer is correct when the volume definition starts with `/` or `./` or `~/` which indeed is for a path. But there is also a case called "`named volumes`"

Comment: Thanks @Colas06, I think I get it. Does that mean I can modify the path on my host by modifying that line in the docker-composer.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Editing the OwnCloud `docker-compose.yml` file to add a bind mount point didn't work for me at all.  It seemed to work only for the first container run and then on subsequent runs I was getting errors suggesting that the database couldn't start.

I ended up finding it a lot easier to have the database stored on the host, disabling redis and using a bind mount for the file storage so I could be assured that I'd always get a reliable state when the container got restarted/removed/etc.

```
export OWNCLOUD_VERSION=10.5.0
export OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=localhost
export ADMIN_USERNAME=***
export ADMIN_PASSWORD=***
export HTTP_PORT=8080

docker run -d \
--net host \
--name owncloud \
-p ${HTTP_PORT}:8080 \
-e OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=${OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN} \
-e OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=pgsql \
-e OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud \
-e OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=*** \
-e OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=*** \
-e OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=localhost \
-e OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME} \
-e OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD} \
-e OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=false \
-e OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis \
-v /blah/data:/mnt/data:rw \
owncloud/server:${OWNCLOUD_VERSION}
```

This code is also nifty to simply place in your system startup file and bang - it all just works.